# Execute javascript  on page load  but not on button click

Tags: javascript

Tried for several times to get below Javscript to execute on page load. Currently it works only on click of "Start" button.

How could this be made excited on load of the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}
function start() {

    var active = document.getElementById("buttonstart").value == "stop";
    getFlashMovie("test").setProperty("src",  !active ? document.getElementById('url2').value: null);
    document.getElementById("start").value = active ? "buttonstart" : "buttonstop";
}
</script>
```

the html

```
  <input id="url2" type="text" value="rtmp://localhost/?streammovie=test"/>
```

The getFlashMovie("test").setProperty is a function to pass variable to the SWF file.
On page load I want it to get executed  rather than on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could do is:

```
<body onload="start();">
```

if you consider using jQuery at all then you could wrap your code within:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      //the code

});
```

the code would execute when the page has been fully loaded, but i do not advise adding the jquery library just so you can use this feature.

Comment: Okay like that, But.. then you would still need to click the button, the start function in itself does not launch the set property only when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

To have your function execute on page load have such code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    start();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}
function start() {

    var active = document.getElementById("buttonstart").value == "stop";
    getFlashMovie("test").setProperty("src",  !active ? document.getElementById('url2').value: null);
    document.getElementById("start").value = active ? "buttonstart" : "buttonstop";
}
start(); //added this
</script>
```

Comment: If the script is located in the `<head>` section it won't work as the elements do not exist yet.

Comment: Just put it in the footer, before the body tag.

Comment: Why force such thing when you can use the `window.onload`?

Comment: Thx that throws an exception like: I had this exception before when I was trying to make it work: getFlashMovie("test").setProperty is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

(10 out of range 3)

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the DOM has been loaded before you attempt to access any elements.
Try to run your `start()` function at the end of the HTML like this;

```
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    start();
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay like that, But.. then you would still need to click the button, the start function in itself does not launch the set property only when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
(function($){

 $(function(){
 // my code comes here
 });     

})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload`  event to fire your code on load.

```
window.onload = function(){

//your code to execute
}
```